# $(A \iff B) \land (C \implies B) \implies (C \implies A)$

Tags: logic

Is the above statement true? Just need a quick confirmation. It makes sense that if A and B are equivalent, and that C implies B then you can "swap" A with B.

Comment: Draw a truth table. You can easily check that this statement is true.

Comment: Or, you can try to falsify the statement by seeing if there is an assignment that makes the premises true, but the conclusion false; find an assignment that makes the consequent false, and see if that same assignment can make the premises be true.

Comment: Your statement about swapping $A$ and $B$ is correct.  In all but the most formal contexts, you do not need any more justification than what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \Leftrightarrow B$ then implicitly $B \Rightarrow A$. We know $C\Rightarrow B$. By transitivity, $C \Rightarrow A$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to show that it true is to make an abbreviated truth table like the one below. Assume that the most precedent connective is false, and then look for a contradiction. You can start by seeing what the first false connective implies about the next level of connectives. And then again we move to the third level of connectives. Now try assigning truth values to $A,B$ and $C$; you will be forced to assign $B$ both a true and false truth value. This is a contradiction, therefore the statement is a tautology, as Newb explained above.
[image]